# A custom filter for excluding posts with specific tags?

Tags: support, tags

I don't have a dual-boot setup, so I will not be able to help much to people with related difficulties; yet this topic makes up a very large percentage of incoming posts.

I have never had an Nvidia graphics card, so I won't be able to help there either.

Is it possible to filter the homepage list to exclude tags, like in this example `dual-boot` and `nvidia`?

(If not possible yet, would a feature request for it stand a chance?)

---

(P.S. seemingly there is no `filter` tag here on Meta and I could not create it; would have been useful for this post.)

Comment: Yeah, my use case was watching the fresh incoming and updated posts on the homepage, because I can learn a lot from them (combined with the chance to sometimes help). So in this sense "I don't know what I'm searching for". I wanted to keep exploring the spectrum of topics, just pull the brake on some of them :) Thanks for the introduction of the related older post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can [ignore tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19177/468333).

1. Hover over to the tag and click " *Ignore Tag*".

   [image]
2. Find "***Ignored Tags***" window on the right side of the homepage, click on ***edit*** and select ***Hide questions in your ignored tags***.

   [image]

---

**Alternatively:** You can always add tags to the ignored tags list.

Comment: Aww you just beat me to it :( +1

Comment: @MarkKirby Uh-oh!!! I saw your comment on the question after posting this. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the effort and swiftness for both of you :) Also, I'm very happy now.

Comment: @Kulfy It dosn't matter, long as OP got helped.

Comment: You can also manage ignored and watched tag in your profile: https://askubuntu.com/users/tag-notifications/current